# Is Littleproxy suitable/ready for production?

Tags: little-proxy

I have been playing with LittleProxy for a while and I am happy with it. I am not wondering how scalable the solution is, and if it is mature enough to be used in a production environment?

Do you use it in production?

Regards

Gilles

Answer (score 0):

We handle all outbound traffic through littleproxy on PRODUCTION. It might be something like 20 000 reqs/min on one instance.